# How to run installed application in Salesforce?

Tags: deployment

I have installed free application of Salesforce. Now I want to run this application (package). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just select the application from the drop down menu, once u select the app,you are landed to the application home page.

while installing application, it will ask the security settings, if you want to see the components, goto setup -> Installed packages

incase of managed package, you are not allowed to editing, but unmanaged package allows changes.

Comment: Application name is not appearing in the list... Am I installed it properly?

Comment: check from setup-> Installed package , u can uninstall from here and install again if you want